# NVD3 / D3.js making xAxis string from date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I'm working on this fiddle example. I had difficult time changing x-Axis value to string(ex: Apple, IBM.. ) I look into .**tickFormat** but still no luck

[Here fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/mRubf/)

```
chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
      var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
      return dx ? d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx)) : '';
      })
  .showMaxMin(false)
  .axisLabel("X-axis Label");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify tick format, This is ur fiddle with string on x axis: http://jsfiddle.net/mRubf/27/

```
   .tickFormat(function(d) {

          return d+' string';
          })
```

Comment: This not exactly what I am looking. you know how dataset has [x,y] I want my data set x to be string input. On example fiddle it's unit time, but I like to change each to String such as APPL, GOGL, IBM..